# Why Taylor series "is convergent" to differential when $\Delta x$, $\Delta y$ go to $0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x,y)$ be a smooth function. Let $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ denote small differences in arguments $x$ and $y$, respectively.

For any $x_0,y_0$ we can find Taylor series centered at that point:

$$f(x_0+\Delta x, y_0 +\Delta y)=f(x_0,y_0)+\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(x_0,y_0)\Delta x+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(x_0,y_0)\Delta y + \frac{1}{2} \frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta x^2}(x_0,y_0)(\Delta x)^2+\frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta x \delta y}(x_0,y_0)(\Delta x)(\Delta y)+\frac{1}{2} \frac{\delta^2 f}{\delta y^2}(x_0,y_0)(\Delta y)^2 + \ldots$$

In MANY books you can read something like that: "As we take $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$  go to $0$, we get

$$df=\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}(x_0,y_0)d x+\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}(x_0,y_0)d y$$.

My question is, how one could treat it in a more rigoruous way. I mean that if $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ go to $0$ then one could say that taking the limit gives us $f(x_0,y_0)=f(x_0,y_0)$. Could someone clarify this to me?

Comment: Are you asking for the [proof of Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Proof_for_Taylor.27s_theorem_in_one_real_variable)?

Comment: @Michael, not at all

Answer (score 0):

We are taking $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ to zero, but not actually ever getting there, you can think of it as setting $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ to be small enough that our function can be approximated very well by a straight line.

In fact what we re doing is sending $\Delta x \rightarrow \delta x$ and $\Delta y \rightarrow \delta y$.

Comment: Ok, but this is still not rigorous. It is the thing that concerns me.

Comment: No you are right, this is an informal way of presenting the arguments. For a rigorous proof you need to look at the proof of taylor, when you say in many books, which ones? Often this informal approach is the approach used in Physics and Engineering textbooks.

Comment: FInancial mathematics, stochastic calculus books. I am familiar with Taylor's theorem and it's proof, but where exactly it corresponds to my question? The proof does not involve "infinitesimals" notation.

Comment: The infinitesimals notation is a non-rigorous way of explaining 'what is happening' it gives an overview and intuitive idea but it is not rigorous. The above expressions can be derived rigorously but you need much deeper mathematics often in differential geometry to do this.

Comment: So there is no "reasonably simple" explanation what happened except for what you wrote?

Comment: I wouldn't like to claim there are no other explanations, better mathematicians than I might have much better ways of explaining it. I'll have a think and see if I can come up with something better.